# Android navigation from sliding menu - fragments or activities?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm upgrading an Android application that used the Dashboard pattern to the Sliding Menu, with a [library by jfeinstein](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu).

Originally I had a DashboardActivity that had 6 buttons, each of which started its corresponding Activity on tap. I also have about 30 other activities that can be started from those "top-level" activities.

Now, I have two possible approaches:

1. Define some kind of MenuActivity, which will include the SlidingMenu fragment, and launch activities on menu items selected, as in the old version.
2. Define only one activity and convert the existing activities to fragments, and show them in a content frame.

When looking at the examples for the sliding menu library, I got the idea that it might be the best approach, as it used switching fragments, but I still think that an Activity is better for a screen than a Fragment.

Is there any reason to use single activity and fragments for content?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Fragments API is your friend. No, Really.

(adapted from the interwebs and Glenn Bech's answer on SO)

#### 1. Re-Usable

Fragments are Android's solution to creating reusable user interfaces. You can achieve some of the same things using activities and layouts (for example by using includes). However; fragments are wired in to the Android API, from HoneyComb, and up.

#### 2. Light Weight

There is a lot of additional responsibility to an Activity since its a primary component. Like providing a context, etc. Without these additional responsibilities, fragments are lightweight and are especially beneficial as you have many of them (when activities are refactored to fragments). Did I mention they are lightweight?

#### 3. Work with the API, not against it

The ActionBar. If you want tabs up there to navigate your app, you quickly see that ActionBar.TabListener inferface gives you a FragmentTransaction as an input argument to the onTabSelected method. You could probably ignore this, and do something else and clever, but you'd be working against the API, not with it.

#### 4. Clever BackStack and customizable too

The FragmentManager handles "back" for you in a very clever way. Back does not mean back to the last activity, like for regular activities. It meeans back to the previous fragment state. This is more awesomed (yes, its a word) by the fact that you can control when and how the backstack is used.

#### 5. Glitter and Glamour

Where the hell do you think all the Hollywood effects come from eh? You can use the cool ViewPager with a  FragentPagerAdapter to create swipe interfaces. The FragmentPagerAdapter code is much cleaner than a regular adapter, and it controls instantiations of the individual fragments. The transition and swipe animations you can apply to fragments are a few things you can't do with Activities.

#### 6. Tablets and phones

Bigger Phone? No it's a Tablet. Your life will be a lot easier if you use Fragments when you try to create applications for both phones and tablets. Since the fragments are so tied in with the Honeycomb+ APIs, you will want to use them on phones as well to reuse code. That's where the compatibility library comes in handy.

#### 7. Phone only man huh?

You even could and should use fragments for apps meant for phones only. If you have portability in mind. I use ActionBarSherlock and the compatibility libraries to create "ICS looking" apps, that look the same all the way back to version 1.6. You get the latest features like the Actionbar, with tabs, overflow, split action bar, viewpager etc.

## One more thing

#### 8. Cross-Communication

The best way to communicate between fragments are intents. When you press something in a Fragemnt you would typically call StartActivity() with data on it. The intent is passed on to all fragments of the activity you launch. It's just easier.

Comment: I hope this is convincing enough :)

Comment: And I though my answer was long haha. Very convincing answer +1 :)

Comment: Nice answer! But let's say for example that my application is like eBay. Does this mean that I only have one activity for the whole app, and a lot of fragments? (Categories, search screen, item screen, seller details screen, item edit screen, your profile screen, login screen) - each of those will be implemented as a Fragment? Then the main activity would become a god object, delivering data from one fragment to another (and back), as with Activities I could have used startActivityForResult.

Comment: @Axarydax I just took a look at the ebay App. It looks like they are having one Main Activty which shows the buttons. The buttons launch a seperate activity when clicked. They are not using Fragments. Yes, you are right you can use startActivityForResult (that's how it's been done all along), but that's one-to-one. If the activity you launched had a bunch of fragments, ALL of them would get this intent, each of them can use only a portion of the data in the intent. The fragments can send an intent to its own activity, that reaches ALL the other fragments in the activity. Voila! no eventbus! :)

Comment: @Axarydax  To do this with activities only, you need to have an event bus or shared data in Application Class. (this part needed to be in the above comment, but the comment became too long). Moreover, the activity itself (God Activity) is not doing anything, it's the android System that's doing all the work passing the intents around via callbacks.

Comment: I see. So for example, the search screen fragment would launch the search results fragment, and the main activity doesn't even need to know about it? (Except for providing the callback for displaying the fragment through a fragment transaction)

Comment: It's something like this. In a way the activity is working like a Controller deciding which View (Fragment) goes where. Of course, you can bleed through the abstraction and make dependencies all over the activity and other fragments. But yes, one can abstract it so that other fragments' presence or which particular activity it's contained in don't matter, and that's how it's meant to be used too.

Comment: @Axarydax one more thing, the fragments get added or removed from the View hierarchy as against launched like activities as you know fragments cannot exist as independent entities, they live inside activities.

Comment: I've ended up using Fragments and it was a nice experience. Thanks!

Comment: @Axarydax I'm really happy for you since something I happened to say on the virtual world here made you happy in the real world. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

> I still think that an Activity is better for a screen than a
> Fragment.

Not in my opinion. I admit it *can* get a little bit complicated to handle with so many fragments, but using fragments has its advantages.

#### 1. Advantage: Scaling across multiple screen sizes.

You can make use of the multi-pane layout pattern to make your app user friendlier to tablet users.
Now you mentioned, that your 6 Activities are calling other Activities as well. Maybe it is possible to reduce the times a user has to click on a screen by using *multiple* screens (fragments) side by side (like already mentioned; the multi-pane layout). I don't know what your app is about, but I could imagine, that the user has to select something from a list and you will be redirecting him to an other Activity based on what he decided to chose. On a tablet you could just use two fragments and display the content on *one* screen (without launching a new one), while you could chose to display only *one* fragment on a handset device (You can do all this by using dynamic and static fragments and by making use of the layout-sw600 etc. folders). You will maintain a good user flow *and* make use of the screen estate of a tablet, if you decide to do this. This will make your app flexible and dynamic.

Take this as a reference:
[image: Awesome use of Fragments]

#### 2. Advantage: Reduce code duplication.

If you chose multiple Activities over using fragments throughout in your app, then you will need to supply the SlidingMenu for *all* your Activities, since a user (talking for myself as a user) expects to use the SlidingMenu everywhere in the app. It would be a bad user experience, if the user has to go "up" the Activity backstack, just to use the SlidingMenu. This will definitely break the user flow. So *you* would have to reimplement the menu in every Activity. Sure you could do that by making a base Activity, but it's much easier to just use one Activity and letting that Activity take care of this issue.

*I can't think of an other Advantage for now. But I'm sure there are many other.*

Answer (score 1):

Guys I've been reading all the posts and I think you are all right. One activity (with many fragments) vs Several Activities.

One main activity full of fragments is not great. Believe me, activity transition, lifecycle, communication between fragments can become a mess if your project has many screens. You have the benefit to share the side menu, which is intended to do so.

On the other side, having one activity per screen type, with no fragments is aonther problem. You have to create a side menu for every activity. Of course using a base class seems easy, but you will also have to restore the state of the menu every time.

Our current solution to this problem is to migrate reduce the number of activities to the minimum and use fragments as much as we can. We will group fragments that share some features into activities. As we are introducing proper tablet support we definetely need to go for fragments.

One last comment. I've managed to decompile the googlePlay store and take a look at the hierarchy. I was really curious about its internal organization. I really thought that google guys would have used only one main activity and several fragments inside -> WRONG. They also use many activities.

Conclusion: We shouldn't be extremists. I think that having just one activity will only work for small projects or simple navigation hierarchies. At the same time, using too many activities can make navigation a mess.